# Excel crashes due (perhaps) to data validation

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA, and trying to write some code that will offer multiple drop down lists across various columns in the same sheet. 
I have the main code as follows, which seems to work (this is in sheet 1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row < 5 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
 Cells(Target.Row, "x").Value = Date
Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub

Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
' returns True if Range1 is within Range2
InRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)
End Function


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyList$, i As Long, c As Range, DoDV As Boolean
Dim d As Range

'Check to see if the cell selected is the right range
On Error Resume Next
If Not InRange(Target, Range("Client_DD")) Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next

Find each active client in the list
For Each c In Sheets("Client data").Range("ClientColumn").Columns(2).Cells 
'Column 2 of the named range has Active/Inactive in it.
If UCase(c.Value) = "ACTIVE" Then
    MyList = MyList & "," & c.Offset(0, -1).Value 'Create a list with all the active clients in
End If
Next c

MyList = Right(MyList, Len(MyList) - 1) 'take off extra comma at the start 
of the list

For Each d In Target.Cells 'We have the right cell selected - do the 
dropdown.

    If InRange(d, Range("Client_DD")) Then

    With d.Validation
        'Add the dropdown
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=MyList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Choose an active client"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True ' change this to false if you don't want the error message
    End With

End If
Next d
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I have additional modules that offer further, more basic drop-downs as follows, ( 4 of these, all following the same format and 2 reference to the same cells)

```
Private Sub main()

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("$C$6:$C$699").Validation
.Delete
 replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Jobs!$C$832:$C$837"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, once the file is saved and re-opened it triggers a run time error. I am suspicious that it is due to some extensive *data validation* option but have checked named ranges etc and am now at a loss! Can anyone offer any guidance on how this might be corrected?

Comment: What is the exact error and which line triggers it?  I'd start by removing any `On Error Resume Next` and fix any problems those may be covering up.

Comment: The line `Find each active client in the list` should cause an error due to the missing leading apostrophe. Follow Tim's advice and come back with more information.

Comment: Narrow down your problem by isolating which procedures work and which not. Post only the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a limitation of 255 characters across the sum of all items in the xlValidateList, this includes the comma delimiter and white space. I can't tell in your code if you are exceeding this as you ae populating the list from your "Active Clients". I suspect though that a list of 'Active Clients' is going to exceed 255 characters. The only workaround is to a) used VSTO as no such limit applies, or b) reference the list to a range of data in an excel table, as again no such limit applies.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to explain the issue entirely. I have managed to find a VBA-free workaround which - although clunky - works for now. Really appreciate your comment, thank you.

Comment: No problems, I spent over a day on the same problem. Do you mind up-voting my answer if it answered your question?